# How can I setup multiple fulfillment options per country in Shopify

Tags: shopify

How can I tell shopify to fulfill the same product via amazon FBA if the person is in the US and to fullfill via oberlo if international? Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FulfillmentOrder API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/fulfillmentorder) to [change](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/fulfillmentorder#move-2020-01) fulfillment location.